# php in_array - can't verify presence of an item

Tags: php

I'm trying to check whether an item exists in an array that is populated from a file, which consists of filenames, one on each line, like this:
GG.jpg

2J.jpg

WWWW.jpg

I have the following so far:

```
$UsedAvatars = array();

$UsedAvatars = file('UsedAvatars.txt',  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

// This next part is to check that the array has been populated, and
// it works.

for($counter=0; $counter<count($UsedAvatars); $counter++)
{
    echo $counter . "\t" . $UsedAvatars[$counter] . "<br>";
}

echo "<br>";

    // This is hardwired in because I know that it is in the text file
    // used to populate the array and so should return TRUE
    $filename="GG.jpg";

if( in_array( $filename, $UsedAvatars ) )
{
  echo "found";
}
```

However, the test does not work and "found" is not outputted. I cannot see what is wrong, can anyone help please?

Comment: Its just a normal text file, with a series of image filenames, ending with jpg, with each filename to a line.

Comment: Strange. It's working for me. Can you try `var_dump($UsedAvatars);` right under the line where you populate it with the file?

Comment: It looks like this:

array(71) { [0]=> string(6) "6M.jpg" [1]=> string(7) "XXX.jpg" [2]=> string(6) "9D.jpg" [3]=> string(7) "10B.jpg"

Comment: I've tried  if( in_array( trim($filename), $UsedAvatars ) )  and that doesn't work either

Comment: You don't have to trim the file name here but the array I think. Or maybe you need to trim both

Comment: You probably have some non-printing whitespace.  Trim the array as Mani suggested. Also, This was voted down in the PHP manual but I found it to be true... windows and macs handle EOL if different ways --- It appears that the 'FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES' flag doesn't remove newlines properly when reading Windows-style text files, i.e. files whose lines end in '\r\n'.

Solution: Always use 'rtrim()' in preference to 'FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES'.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
if( in_array( $filename, $UsedAvatars ) )
{
  echo "found";
}
```

to

```
$tmp = array_flip ($UsedAvatars);
if ($tmp[$filename] != "")
    echo "found";
```